# Websocket issue using OWASP Zap proxy

Tags: proxy, websocket, zap

I work with zap 2.4.3 but I don't receive websocket traffic, seems it block only websocket packet while http and https cross correctly through the proxy There's something to configure in order to allow it ?

My system is:

- ZAP 2.4.3
- Scientific Linux 6.7
- java version "1.8.0_20-ea"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-ea-b05)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b05, mixed mode)
- Firefox 44.0.2
  (I've also tried Opera 35)

Everything works well with either Firefox or Opera if I don't use the proxy.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Strange, sounds like an issue we're not aware of.
Could you either raise an issue https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues or ask on the ZAP User Group: http://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users ?